# Is it possible to force a Python library to install a specific version of one of its dependency?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, scipy

I would like to install scikit-learn==0.24.0 and scipy==1.7.1 which is one of its dependencies.
Scikit-learn needs a version of scipy that is >=0.19.1.

I have the following requirements.txt :

```
scipy==1.7.1
scikit-learn==0.24.0
```

So,

1. it downloads scipy 1.7.1
2. it downloads scikit-learn 0.24.0.
3. It downloads scipy again with the 1.7.3 version

Version of Python: 3.7
Version of Pip: 18.1

I would like to have scipy download only the first time. How can it be done?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.9 and the requirements.txt file shown. `pip install -r requirements.txt` only downloads and installs scipy-1.7.1.

Comment: The version of Python I used is 3.7. Do you mean that in your environment, the installation is done only once?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.7, either. Only scipy-1.7.1 is downloaded (once) and installed (once). No mention of scipy-1.7.3 ever appears.

Comment: I also can't reproduce w/ the MWE provided. Is it possible the `requirements.txt` file you are actually using is bigger? Maybe `scipy` is accidentally listed twice, or it's not at the top? Used a new/clean `conda` env to test w/ 3.7 (windows WSL)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the problem. I have pip 18.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

It was due to pip.

With pip 18.1, it doesn't work.
With pip 21.3, it works.

I have upgraded pip.

---

---

Answer (score 0):

(Using the answer box to provide a formatted code.) Works for me: Debian Linux, Python 3.7, pip 21.3.1:

```
$ mktmpenv -p python3.7

(tmp-bf2774e21725ffd2) $ echo "scipy==1.7.1
> scikit-learn==0.24.0" > requirements.txt

(tmp-bf2774e21725ffd2) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting scipy==1.7.1
  Downloading scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.5 MB)
     |################################| 28.5 MB 12.0 MB/s            
Collecting scikit-learn==0.24.0
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.24.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (22.3 MB)
     |################################| 22.3 MB 11.4 MB/s            
Collecting numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5
  Downloading numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
     |################################| 15.7 MB 14.5 MB/s            
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
     |################################| 306 kB 11.2 MB/s            
Installing collected packages: numpy, threadpoolctl, scipy, joblib, scikit-learn
Successfully installed joblib-1.1.0 numpy-1.21.5 scikit-learn-0.24.0 scipy-1.7.1 threadpoolctl-3.0.0
```